# React - Dynamic routed wrapper which render any component passed

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

Most of my pages shared the same HTML around them but there are a couple of pages like LOGIN which looks entirely different. To solve this issue I created a component with the name LoggedInWrapper which should add all HTML that is shared for logged-in users like menu, breadcrumbs, etc. Code looks like:

```
export const LoggedInWrapper = ({ component: Component }: any) => {

    return (
    <div className="content flex-column-fluid" id="kt_content">
        // Breadcrumbs and Menu comes here
        <div className="row">       
            <div className="col-xl-12">
                <Component/>
             </div>                         
    </div>

    )
}
```

So basically what I want is to pass any component here and it gets rendered, In general, I feel like this logic is fine however I'm not sure how to pass child component in my App.tsx as currently I have something like

```
    <PrivateRoute path="/my-path/:id" component={LoggedInWrapper} />
    <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
    <Route path="/forgot-password" exact component={ForgotPassword} />
```

and if I try

```
<PrivateRoute path="/admin-edit-member/:id" component={LoggedInWrapper<MyOtherComponent>} />
```

it start complaining about invalid syntax.

My PrivateRoute looks like:

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }: any) => {
  const { currentUser } = useAuth()
 
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props => {
        if (currentUser) {
          return <Component {...props} />
        }
        return <Redirect to="/login" />;
      }}      
    ></Route>
  )
}
```

Any suggestions how to do something like I need?

Thanks!

Comment: you can use the [render](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func) prop of the `Route` component. You could also pass the `LoggedInWrapper` component as a child component of the `PrivateRoute` component.

Comment: Sorry, most likely I am not smart enough, how exactly I can do that? I already have `PriveRoute` which basically looks like this: https://pastebin.com/5RJWa1G1 but I'm not sure how to reuse same pattern for my need :)

Comment: Include the `PrivateRoute ` component in your question.

Comment: @Yousaf just did :)

Comment: You could pass `MyOtherComponent` as a second prop to `PrivateRoute` component and then from there pass it to the `Component`.

Comment: can I kindly ask you for a code example? 
I tried this: https://pastebin.com/8S0ztRCz and getting error : `Cannot find name 'childComponent'.ts(2304)`

Comment: Can you create a minimal, reproducible example? You can use codesandbox or stackblitz to create a demo and share the link.